# Disable find and replace feature in OpenOffice.org

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer, find-and-replace

Can you disable the find and replace feature in OpenOffice.org Writer?

We are a school, and the students are cheating by using this feature to avoid reading the entire document.

We're looking for a way to lock or disable this feature from being used. Is there a configuration or setting that can set this up?

Comment: i am referring to the edit/find&replace feature.  we are a school, and the students are cheating by using this feature to avoid reading the entire document.

Comment: Even if you disable it on OpenOffice, they can copy the entire text to another text editing program (e.g. notepad, wordpad) and use CTRL+F as well.

Comment: Learning search/scan skills is actually not a bad thing.  Instead of doomed technological fixes, just quiz them on the content, which they'll only know if they've read the whole thing.

Comment: @ [Mehper](http://superuser.com/users/13567/mehper-c-palavuzlar): you can put down your comment as the answer  @ [dan eckstrom](http://superuser.com/users/63629/dan-eckstrom) : please edit your question and put what you wrote in comments there , makes the question clearer

Comment: @Shark: Please refer to [How comment @replies work](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/43019/133693), your way of addressing doesn't result in @Mehper getting notified of your comment

Comment: As a teacher myself, let me *strongly* agree with CarlF's comment. The problem is with your lousy assignment, not with their perfectly rational method of finding the answer.

Answer (score 1):

See :

[OpenOffice Customizing the User Interface](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/Administration_Guide/Customizing_the_UI)
[Customizing OpenOffice.org](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Migration_Guide/Customizing)

Comment: Why under-vote, for bloody hell ?

Comment: I'm guessing its because of this: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/500/is-downvoting-link-only-answers-acceptable (Or at least the principle behind the post on Meta)

Comment: If I start copying entire articles into my answers, I'll surely get down-voted for the opposite reason.

Comment: "This answer is not useful" is and more like a comment than actually helping. Plus, this answer is akin to "figure it out for yourself somewhere else"

Comment: @random: My answer is more like "the links contain a description of the process with screenshots, much better than anything I could do in a couple of sentences".

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*I formerly posted this as a comment but now reposting as an answer.*</sub>

Even if you disable find & replace feature in OpenOffice, your students can copy the entire text to another text editing program (e.g. notepad, wordpad, etc.) and use CTRL+F as well. In short, you cannot prevent them from searching and replacing just by blocking this feature in OpenOffice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the file to **.HTML**, open that in a browser and set that **browser in full-screen mode**.
2. **Remove the keyboard which restricts them to scrolling** with the mouse.

   Let them write their answers on a piece of paper instead...
3. Although that should be enough,
   you can also [**disable right clicking**](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/noright.htm) by pasting a piece of code before `</body>`.

Comment: This answer is a *reductio ad absurdum* of the question.